# Yii UrlManager suffix exclusion

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am working on a project that is using **Yii2 framework**. In the **UrlManager** configuration section I have declared several rules, and added suffix (.html) for all pages.

Now I should have a admin page, which should be accessed like `www.mydomain/admin`, but it doesn't work, because it expects to be `.../admin.html`.

So is there any way to 'overload' the suffix option for specific cases.

Here is the snippet from my config/main.php file

```
'urlManager' => [
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'class'=>'app\components\LangUrlManager',
'suffix' => '.html',
'rules'=>[
    '/' => 'page/index',
    'page/new' => 'page/new',
    'page/<slug:\w+>' => 'page/view',
    'admin' => 'site/login',
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like that:

```
'rules'=>[
    '/' => 'page/index',
    'page/new' => 'page/new',
    'page/<slug:\w+>' => 'page/view',
    [                    
     'pattern' => 'admin',                   
     'route' => 'site/login',                    
     'suffix' => '',                
    ]
    ]
],
```